# Adjective ordering program or library

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a program or library that can take as input one noun and a list of adjectives, and outputs the correct [noun phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) comprising those noun and adjectives. E.g. if the input is `purple, nice, car`, the output should be `nice purple car`. If several orderings are possible, then list them all.

Free, open source and compatible with Windows 7 is preferred. I'm mostly interested in English, but French would be nice too if available.

Comment: Maybe [Stanford NLP API](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/)